# Custom naming for page layers Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Using Cognos 10.2.1 and reporting studio. Im generating a report with the page layers filter context option. However, the names are automatically generated based on the page name. For example, if the page name is Hello, it beocomes Hello_2,Hello_3,Hello_4.If I'm filtering by Location, could it be possible for the page to be name by region instead of Hello_2,etc..

Answer (score 0):

This is possible only starting in version 10.2.2:
[enter link description here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_10.2.2/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cra.10.2.2.doc/t_ug_cra_adv_prop_name_worksht_tabs_excel2007.html)